# Data extraction using Azure Cognitive services

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding, data-extraction

Goodday!

I've got a library full of documents. I would like to be able to know some more about these documents without reading through all of them. On the first page of each document I already put some relevant information about the document such as year of creation, author, number of pages and confidentiality.

I want to use some AI to browse through these documents and decide which is what and return it to me so I can store it in a CSV or something. This way I'll be able to easily find the right document.

Now, I did use LUIS and some of the TAA service of Azure's cognitive services before. But I cannot figure out a way how to accomplish this.
Is it theoretically possible to send the first page (using a powershell script to cut the rest of the document and send it through) to LUIS, which can then return the entities? I'd like them in a way: Date of creation: 18/10/2018, pages: 100.

Or is there a better way to use Azure's powerfull AI to get this done?

Comment: Where exactly you need AI? Or you need only to extract Entities using script? Wouldn't regex do the job then?

Comment: I cannot be sure every document is EXACTLY the same. regex could do, but if I have two names in my datatext which are used in different context it won't work.

Comment: What makes you believe AI would surpass this gap? Regex could do more than "exact match". Could you provide any comparable examples?

Comment: What is TAA? LUIS does return entities, but its main purpose is to return an intent, usually from a message sent from a user to a bot. As I understand it, you are trying to create a tool/script and not a bot. Is that correct?